# Get tomcat to start context(s) immediately

Tags: linux, arch-linux, tomcat

How would I get Tomcat to start/init a context *immediately* when the service starts? Currently the context is only loaded and initialized on the first page view.

Is this something that has to be done in the `web.xml` file? I'd likely to do this per-context if at all possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a ServletContextListener for each context. You can find an example [here](http://www.javabeat.net/2009/02/servletcontextlistener-example/).